# How do I get the file creation time in Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows

How can I get the file creation time in Ruby on Windows?

`File.ctime` is supposed to return change time.

`dir /tc` in cmd.exe returns creation time with bunch of other stuff.

Is there a better way than exec'ing it and parsing?

Comment: filectime returns creation time in php on windows, is it the same with ruby's File.ctime?

Comment: Windows stores creation times. Unix systems do not. Mac OS stores it in meta information but Ruby can not access it directly using the `File` methods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, the "ctime" ("creation" or "change" time) metadata attribute of a file is [system dependent](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/c6476c819044046f/f650cc19a41dd62e?pli=1) as some systems (e.g. Windows) store the time that a file was created (its "birth date") and others (Posix systems, e.g. Linux) track the time that it was last updated.  Windows uses the ctime attribute [as the actual creation time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_times#Change_time_and_creation_time_.28ctime.29), so you can use the various `ctime` functions in Ruby.

The [File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) class has static and instance methods named `ctime` which return the last modified time and [File::Stat](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File/Stat.html#M002606) has an instance method (which differs by not tracking changes as they occur).

```
File.ctime("foo.txt") # => Sun Oct 24 10:16:47 -0700 2010 (Time)

f = File.new("foo.txt")
f.ctime # => Will change if the file is replaced (deleted then created).

fs = File::Stat.new("foo.txt")
fs.ctime # => Will never change, regardless of any action on the file.
```

Comment: "ctime" is **not** the creation time on Linux but the inode or file change time. It will be updated whenever the file is moved, altered, permissions or owner are altered.