# How can I set a file creation time with ruby on Mac OS?

Tags: ruby, macos, file, filesystems, ctime

I'm trying to set the filesystem creation time for a file on Mac OS using a ruby script.

On Mac OS X the 'ctime' represents the last time of inode modification rather than the file creation time, thus using ruby's File.utime() to set ctime will not help.

Using this hint [ http://inessential.com/2008/12/18/file_creation_date_in_ruby_on_macs ] I can retrieve a file's creation time:

```
Time.parse(`mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw "#{filename}"`)
```

...but any idea on how to set it using ruby?

-- UPDATE --

Okay, I think I **can** actually do this with `File.utime` in ruby.

Even though the ctime is technically not used by Mac OS to track file creation time, when you use `utime` to update the *ctime* (along with the *mtime*, which must be simultaneously set) the filesystem appears to magically also update the creation time as per `kMDItemContentCreationDate`.

So to set *filename* to a ctime of 1st Oct 2010 and a mtime of 2nd Oct 2010:

```
File.utime(Time.strptime('011010', '%d%m%y'), Time.strptime('021010', '%d%m%y'), filename)
```

Comment: you might want to post your 'update' you solution as answer, so this question doesn't need to remain open (and 'unanswered')

Comment: You do understand this is not portable. Linux doesn't support storing a creation time. Also ctime is not creation time, it is "change" time according to the directory, not for the file itself. This might explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4009369/128421

Comment: Setting the file times using `utime` does NOT change the value returned using `mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a Ruby solution with the method `utime`. But you will have to set modification time (mtime) and access time (atime) **at once**. If you want to keep access time you could use:

```
File.utime(File.atime(path), modification_time, path)
```

See [Ruby core documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) as well.

Comment: If you run `stat -s` on that file you will see that this does not update the `st_ctime` property.

Comment: This doesn't work in macOS 13.0. `File.utime` updates mtime but not created in Finder

Answer (score 3):

So you've definitely got a pure Ruby solution working, but since this is OS X, are you opposed to `exec()` or `system()` and just using `touch`? In your case, I'd almost prefer:

```
system "touch -t YYYYMMDDhhmm /what/ever"
```

if for no other reason than clarity.

Comment: `touch` doesn't use the same mechanism that `mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate -raw` does.

Comment: This doesn't work in macOS 13.0. `-t` or `-mt` both only modify mtime. Need to use `SetFile` like Stan's example

Answer (score 3):

This works for me to update creation time on OS X 10.11.1:

```
system "SetFile -d '#{time.strftime "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"}' #{file}"
```

No claims of portability - SetFile is an OS X command (and the man page says it's deprecated with XCode 6, so may not work for very long) - couldn't find another way to do it though, `Time.utime` didn't update creation time, but only modified and accessed time.

See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/99536/65787

Answer (score 0):

Ruby uses the utimes system call to change the file-times.

Reading the man-page for utimes explains what happens:

int
     utimes(const char *path, const struct timeval *times);
..
If times is non-NULL, it is assumed to point to an array of two timeval
     structures.  The access time is set to the value of the first element,
     and the modification time is set to the value of the second element.  For
     file systems that support file birth (creation) times (such as UFS2), the
     birth time will be set to the value of the second element if the second
     element is older than the currently set birth time.  To set both a birth
     time and a modification time, two calls are required; the first to set
     the birth time and the second to set the (presumably newer) modification
     time.  ...

So ctime only get updated backwards in time.