# Is there any way could I read File's Created time and Date?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way could I read the File's Created time and date? For an instance, I am creating a file today 10'O clock, I want to get the this time and Date of today, Is there any predefined function is there in Ruby?

Comment: You might want to refer [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009288/how-do-i-get-the-file-creation-time-in-ruby-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

[`File.stat("file.test").ctime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-ctime) is what you are looking for.

> Returns the change time for stat (that is, the time directory information about the file was changed, not the file itself).
>
> Note that on Windows (NTFS), returns creation time (birth time).
>
> ```
> File.stat("testfile").ctime   #=> Wed Apr 09 08:53:14 CDT 2003
> ```

Comment: Unless other file information are also needed, it's probably better to just use [File.ctime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-ctime).

Comment: hi, Thanks, but it returns to me in different format, It look like '2014-12-25 02:26:27 -0800', What to do to bring the format you described? My code is 'puts File.stat("hi.rb").ctime'

Comment: @RAJ the method returns a `Time` instance. You can use `Time` object methods to format it.

Comment: hi, thanks, But I have another problem when I give the path as a filename, like " File.stat(Dir["C:/Raj/Project/Output/Reports/*"].first).ctime", Now it's returning the creation time of output folder not result file which I am expecting, what is the reason? For you info, the output folder reside in the same folder of executabe rb file.

Comment: `File.ctime` is returning the time the file was modified on OSX for me. Not the creation time.